# angularJs : how to load table data after clicking a button?

Tags: javascript, html, json, angularjs

Hello Everyone im sorry if my question is being so long this is my first question in Stack over flow :) ; i'm new to angularJs so im facing this problem
i was trying to make a a button that load json data that i retrieve by http.get function  to a table with ng-repeat 
and i wanted to make the data be loaded after i click a button

**Angular:**

```js
app.controller('dayRecord', function ($scope, $http) {
    var date = dateToString("dailyData")
        ,http;
    $scope.headers = ["company", "ticker", "ccy", "last", "close", "chg", "bid", "ask", "trades", "volume", "turnover"];
    //LoadDate : function to load StockRecords for a given day
    $scope.loadData = function () {

        http = "http://localhost:63342/nasdak/app/data?date=";//the REST service Server to fetch the day stock recrod json data
        http += date; //
        $http.get(http)
            .success(function (response) {
                console.log(response);

                $scope.first = response.balticMainList;
                $scope.columnSort = {sortColumn: 'turnover', reverse: true};
            });

    }
    $scope.loadData();
});
```

as you see here there is :
dayRecord Controller
loadData function that gets the json data

and here is the html code for the table im trying to load

**HTML**

```html
<div ng-controller="dayRecord" style="display: inline;">
        <label for="dailyData">Show Stock For Day :</label>
        <input type="text" id="dailyData" name="dailyData" >
        <button id = "dailyStocksLoad" ng-click="loadData()">load</button>
    </div>
<div class ="dailyViewContainer" ng-controller="dayRecord">

    <div >
        <h1>Baltic Main List</h1>
        <table id ="myTable" >
            <thead>
            <tr >
                <th  ng-repeat="header in headers " ng-click="columnSort.sortColumn=header;columnSort.reverse=!columnSort.reverse">{{header}}</th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="x in first | orderBy:columnSort.sortColumn:columnSort.reverse">
                <td style="text-align: left">{{ x.company }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.ticker }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.ccy }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.last }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.close }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.chg }}% </td>
                <td>{{ x.bid }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.ask }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.trades }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.volume }}</td>
                <td>{{ x.turnover }}</td>
            </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
```

when i call the function inside the controller everything works fine

```js
 app.controller('dayRecord', function ($scope, $http) {
        ...
        $scope.loadData = function () {
        ...
        }
        
        
        $scope.loadData();
    });
```

but when i click the button to load the data dynamically i cannot load it i even checked the response  with console.log(response) it shows that http.get is retrieving the data but it's not refreshing it on the table

Comment: add sample json data in question

Answer (score 2):

Hmm maybe the issue is that you are assigning 2 pieces of html to the same controller. What about wrapping the whole html into 1 div element and put ng-controller there like below:

```
<div ng-controller="dayRecord">
  <div style="display: inline;">
    <label for="dailyData">Show Stock For Day :</label>
    <input type="text" id="dailyData" name="dailyData" >
    <button id = "dailyStocksLoad" ng-click="loadData()">load</button>
  </div>
  <div class ="dailyViewContainer">

  <div >
    <h1>Baltic Main List</h1>
    <table id ="myTable" >
        <thead>
        <tr >
            <th  ng-repeat="header in headers " ng-click="columnSort.sortColumn=header;columnSort.reverse=!columnSort.reverse">{{header}}</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr ng-repeat="x in first | orderBy:columnSort.sortColumn:columnSort.reverse">
            <td style="text-align: left">{{ x.company }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.ticker }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.ccy }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.last }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.close }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.chg }}% </td>
            <td>{{ x.bid }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.ask }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.trades }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.volume }}</td>
            <td>{{ x.turnover }}</td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: i appreciate your help but it didn't work i'm still stuck .

Comment: after another try it worked , you are awesome thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Angular might need some help in changing the DOM. Try to add $scope.$apply() to the end of your load data function and see what happens on the console.

Comment: i added $scope.$apply();
i got this 

`Error: $apply already in progress

    at Error (native)

    at g (http://localhost:63342/nasdak/angularjs.js:85:56)

    at Object.e.$apply 
(http://localhost:63342/nasdak/angularjs.js:89:137)

    at Object.$scope.loadData (http://localhost:63342/nasdak/app/app.js:46:16)

    at http://localhost:63342/nasdak/angularjs.js:73:48

    at http://localhost:63342/nasdak/angularjs.js:145:148

    at Object.e.$eval (http://localhost:63342/nasdak/angularjs.js:89:47)

    at Object.e.$apply 
(http://localhost:63342/nasdak/angularjs.js:89:154)